# How do I access cookie array child variable

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

How do I access user_id:
This is the print_r of my cookie:

```
Array
(
     [PHPSESSID] => gv0hsh6uel9kiuprdoc0uqboq4
     [oauth_token] => 40533855-FNM77JeuJIPdKclYyaT2Fi9jZRu2NGAHh5FeveNk
     [oauth_token_secret] => C6GDTEu60rGa4aDbqjncm6yfUf9Xc9520AuX9GXag
     [SocialAuth] => a:2:{s:4:"type";s:8:"facebook";s:7:"user_id";s:2:"22";}
     [__utma] => 157144508.1187834205.1333154906.1333154906.1333154906.1
     [__utmb] => 157144508.35.10.1333154906
     [__utmc] => 157144508
     [__utmz] => 157144508.1333154906.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
)
```

My user ID in this is at the end of the SocialAuth line... "22". But I cant seem to access it.

```
$user = $_COOKIE["SocialAuth"]["user_id"];
```

Returns "a".

Am I doing this right?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a serialized array in `$_COOKIE['SocialAuth']`. Take a look at the manual pages for [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Use unserialize like this to access the user id:

```
$user = unserialize($_COOKIE['SocialAuth'])['user_id'];
```

Or prior to PHP 5.4:

```
$arr = unserialize($_COOKIE['SocialAuth']);
$user = $arr['user_id'];
```